# Ubuntu PXE server for Windows 10 x64 PE (live) with Wimboot

Tags: boot, pxe, tftp

I'm just trying to create an Ubuntu PXE server to boot over LAN Windows 10 x64 PE from .wim file by wimboot.

I've installed isc-dhcp-server and configured /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf:

```
default-lease-time 86500;
max-lease-time 6059934;
ddns-update-style none;
authoritative;
log-facility local7;

allow booting;
allow bootp;

subnet 10.10.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
  range 10.10.0.2 10.10.0.250;
  option broadcast-address 10.10.0.255;
  option domain-name "local";
  option domain-name-servers 8.8.8.8;
    filename = "syslinux.efi";
}
```

Installed and configured /etc/default/tftpd-hpa:

```
TFTP_USERNAME="tftp"
TFTP_DIRECTORY="/tftpboot"
TFTP_ADDRESS=":69"
TFTP_OPTIONS="--ipv4 --secure -d -l  --blocksize 4096 --create --permissive --verbose"
RUN_DAEMON="yes"
```

Created menu entry:

```
LABEL ^1) Load W10mini +++
  TEXT HELP
    Boot with wimboot
  ENDTEXT
com32 linux.c32 /wimboot/wimboot
APPEND initrdfile=/BOOTMGR,/Boot/BCD,/MIPE/BOOT/MIPE.SDI,/MIPE/BOOT/MIPE64.WIM
```

I'm booting in UEFI-mode, on the screen I'm getting messages "Encapsulating..." OK at the end "Encapsulating /MIPE/BOOT/MIPE64.WIM" AND AFTER 4 MINUTES MY COMPUTER REBOOTS!!! (client not server)

I've tried some other .WIM files, tried other computers to be host and servers-the same: no luck.

Can anybody give me advice, idea or some help...?

UPD: I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS

Comment: Hello. This is a Windows question and therefore off topic on this site. Yes I see you are using a unknown version Ubuntu server to host but it is a Windows system you are trying to install.

Comment: No, I don't touch Windows at all. Everything I'm doing in Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS